# how do i validate the referenced object of another object (DTO) in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator, modelattribute

> ***my UserDto class is here:***

```
package com.carpoint.dto;

import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

import com.carpoint.validation.annotation.PasswordMatches;

@PasswordMatches
public class UserDto{

    @NotEmpty
    private String username;

    @NotEmpty @Size(min=6, max=30)
    private String password;

    @NotEmpty
    private String confirmPassword;

    @NotEmpty
    private String firstname;
    @NotEmpty
    private String lastname;
    @NotEmpty @Email
    private String email;

    private UserAddressDto userAddress;

    //getters & setters
}
```

> ***and UserAddressDto class here:***

```
package com.carpoint.dto;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

public class UserAddressDto {

    @NotEmpty
    private String address;
    @NotEmpty
    private String country;
    @NotEmpty
    private String city;
    @NotEmpty
    private Integer pincode;

        //getters & setters
    }
```

---

### My question is that the validation on UserDto is working successfully but it's not on referenced type of UserAddressDto and I want to validate UserDto's referenced type is there any way?

---

> ***and here is my UserController code snippet:***

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String addUsers(@Valid @ModelAttribute("userDto")UserDto userDto, 
ModelMap model, SessionStatus status, RedirectAttributes attributes) 
throws IOException {
    ....
    ....
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try putting `@Valid` upon `private UserAddressDto userAddress;` in class `UserDto`? I guess that should be enough as spring handles it on its own.

Comment: your idea is good but getting this error

HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Size' validating type 'java.lang.Integer'. Check configuration for 'userAddress.pincode'

Comment: That's because you're using `@NotEmpty` for an Integer. It's absolutely wrong. It is only used for `String, Array or Collections`. Use `@NotNull` for pincode.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was struggling with this issue from last few days then I decided to ask a question on stackoverflow...

Thanks again :)